# change nuxt.config.js from ftp

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have site(NUXT) on ftp. I need change js file, it is included in nuxt.config.js. When I changed them by ftp, nothing has changed on site. I need regenerate site on server? What command I need?

Comment: Depends of your configuration. Overall, I do not recommend using FTP nowadays.

Comment: Overall, check your `package.json` and run the command that you're using to build your app locally (before sending it via FTP).